# Why we use async before function in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Sometimes we use async before the function. I want to know why and what is the proper use of async.

```
async remove(id) {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:9022/users/delete/'+id)
      .then(res => {
        let updatedUsers = [...this.state.users].filter(i => i.id !== id);
        this.setState({users: updatedUsers});
      });
  }
```

& what is the meaning of this

```
Users.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Refer to async await MDN documentation and you'll get more clarity. To answer your second question, that is how you add validation in react for your components.

Comment: I don't know why 'we' use it here because `await` isn't used, and the function doesn't benefit from being `async`. *& what is the meaning of this* - this is a different question. Consider asking it as such.

Answer (score 0):

> An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously
>   via the event loop, using an implicit Promise to return its result...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Async functions basically allow us to have nicer syntax for anything that does an asynchronous operation (API call, DB query, timeout, etc...).

We you define a function as async, you gain access to the `await` keyword, which prevents you from having to deal with callback functions or promise chaining.

For example:

```
async function foo() {
    let example = await apiQuery();
    ...
}
```

If you didn't specify a function as `async`, you would have to do it this way.

```
function foo() {
    apiQuery().then((data) => console.log(data));
    ...
}
```

You can see the first example provides a more clear approach to dealing with `async` functions. Working with multiple `async` function calls can start to get messy without it.

As for your second question.

PropTypes are a way of telling other developers that your React component requires some external input (props) to work correctly. So in your case, the Users component requires a prop titled classes that is of the type `Object`

See more here - https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: `foo` aren't equivalent. Second foo doesn't return a promise. It's untestable and potentially unusable.